# can contenteditable DIV can have rounded outline

Tags: jquery, css

After browsing some questions about contenteditable, I have found out that I can change the color and the width of the border (using outline) but since it's not a border I can't find a way to make the outline rounded like "border-radius".

How can I achieve such thing ?

Thanks

Edit:
I have found something that worked for me:

```
       .editableDiv {
          margin-bottom: 5px;
          outline: 0px solid transparent;
          padding:5px;
        }
        .editableDiv:hover {
          outline: 0px solid transparent;
          box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #ccc inset;
          border-radius: 10px;
        }
```

Comment: Please tell What have your tried: mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: At present this can only be done in Firefox, using `-moz-outline-radius`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/-moz-outline-radius

Comment: @OllyHodgson, I need it in all browsers

Comment: Why do you use outline for border, and not the actual border?

Comment: @Floremin, because in contenteditable:focus the border rule doesn't affect anything

Comment: @Alon You can't do it with `outline` then. You could use `border` instead of `outline`, or you might be able to emulate it by combining `box-shadow` and `border-radius`.

Comment: @OllyHodgson, exactly what I've tried and it worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no defined way to accomplish this(as of now), generally what I use is a hard shadow

```
div {
    background: #eeeeee;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin: 30px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #000 inset;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WsZsF/)

Comment: The `outline` property is too inconsistent for the job atm (especially on focus of contenteditable elements). Good alternative! +1